# Ajax Balloon Extender With Tab Container , Display Blank on Page Load

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, popup-balloons

I'm working on a website, when i run it , the balloon show up with blank text, when i i click on the Target Control the balloon disappear from the old position and show up again in the correct position >> Top Right of the Text Box.

i figured out that the Tab container allow the Balloon show up each time the page load run.

How i can hide it when page load run and show it only  when target Control  click.

This what happen at first :
[Work On PageLoad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h21QK.jpg)
And here when i click on the target:
[TargerClick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FApM6.jpg)
my HTML is

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="test" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
                <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>

        <div>
            <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server">
                <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_SMSBody" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="391px" Height="200px" Style="margin: 0 auto; direction: ltr; font-size: medium; padding: 10px;"></asp:TextBox>
                        <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="txt_SMSBody_TextBoxWatermarkExtender" runat="server" BehaviorID="txt_SMSBody_TextBoxWatermarkExtender" TargetControlID="txt_SMSBody" WatermarkText="Click Here to show up the Balloon.."></ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                        <ajaxToolkit:BalloonPopupExtender ID="txt_SMSBody_BalloonPopupExtender" BehaviorID="Ba" runat="server" Enabled="true" TargetControlID="txt_SMSBody" BalloonPopupControlID="pnl_SMSBody" Position="TopRight">
                            <Animations>
                                            <OnShow>
                                                <Sequence>
                                                    <HideAction Visible="true" />
                                                    <FadeIn Duration=".5" Fps="20" />
                                                </Sequence>
                                            </OnShow>
                                            <OnHide>
                                              <FadeOut Duration=".5" Fps="20" />
                                            </OnHide>
                            </Animations>
                        </ajaxToolkit:BalloonPopupExtender>
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnl_SMSBody" runat="server" Style="padding: 15px;">The Correct Place is here, TopRight of the TextBox</asp:Panel>
                        <br />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
            </ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```